# DeleteCriticalSection VS delete criticalSection

Tags: c++-cli

What is difference between following codes

```
void foo()
{
  CRITICAL_SECTION csection;
  InitializeCriticalSection(&csection);
  EnterCriticalSection(&csection);
  // some code goes here 
  delete csection;
} 


void foo()
{
  CRITICAL_SECTION csection;
  InitializeCriticalSection(&csection);
  EnterCriticalSection(&csection);
  // some code goes here 
  DeleteCriticalSection(&csection);
}
```

which is best way to dispose the **csection** object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keyword `delete` is for things allocated with `new` or `gcnew`, only. The *only* way to clean up a critical section is the `DeleteCriticalSection` method.